# How is mutability different from assigning a new value to a variable?

Tags: theory, mutable

Say you have a variable:

```
var x = [1,2]
```

If it is a mutable object, you could do:

```
x.append(3)
x
>> [1,2,3]
```

But if it is immutable, and you wanted to change the value of x, you would effectively have to do:

```
// init x
var x = [1,2]
// add a 3 to x
x = [1,2,3]
x
>> [1,2,3]
```

What's the difference between mutability and just changing the variable?

My best guess is that when you do `append(3)` it is modifying a reference to the same variable in memory, but when you `x = [1,2,3]`, you possibly declaring a new variable x, referencing a new block in memory, and deallocating the old block that `x=[1,2]` occupied.

It seems like immutable variables should not be able to change. But many times we want immutable variables to change. For example, in React, state variables are considered immutable. But the point of having state is so that the variables can change. So to change the values of them you need to go through these very roundabout ways, like calling `setState()`, and feeding it callback functions if you want to do something like append an element to a list.

Comment: The difference is that if two variables reference the same object, mutating it via one reference means any changes are also visible through the other reference; whereas if you create a new object with a different state and assign it to one variable, the other variable still holds a reference to the original unchanged object.

Comment: I see, does this mean that "mutability" as a concept is mostly relevant to languages without pointers?

Comment: I don't see how that follows; a pointer is a kind of reference.

Comment: The idea of immutability is simply that a variable not change, i.e. the value of a variable always be what it was when it was initialised. This has lots of benefits and lots of drawbacks. In both the append case and the reassigning x case the value of the variables stops being what it was when it was initalised, so neither example has x being immutable. I would say that looking at immutability through the lens of React is confusing the matter, it's an idea in its own right, which yes React uses and yes it makes some things tedious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are variables and there are values. Variables are like names or addresses by which we refer to values. Mutability applies to values, not variables.

A mutable value can be changed in-place without creating a new value. For instance, if I create an integer value and assign it the value of one, I can then increment that value without allocating space for a new integer; the value is incremented in-place. Any references to that value will all immediately see the change because they are referring to the one value that has now been changed - or mutated.

Immutable values cannot be changed in-place. Suppose strings are immutable in our language. If I create a string and initialize it to the value "hello world", it is not possible to change that value without creating space for a new string. If I want to change the value to "goodbye world", I must create a new string value with newly allocated memory. Any variables that referred to the original value will continue to do so unless they are updated to refer to the new value.

Constancy is a similar concept that applies to variables and has to do with whether the thing being referenced by the variable is allowed to change. This gets muddied a bit with primitive types; really, a const int variable should be incrementable since incrementing the int doesn't change the memory being referred to, just the stuff inside that memory. However, constant/readonly lists can typically be added to and removed from without issue, for instance, so the distinction between constancy (of variable reference) and immutability (of value) is a little more well-preserved there.

Answer (score -1):

So when you declare a new variable, you create a variable and the corresponding value stored in RAM,  if you use variable = value statement then you create a new value totally has nothing to do with the old value, the old value never change ,it's immutable. New value get assigned to the same variable and then you call the same variable it just point to a different location in RAM, old location never change, you create a new one to replace it.